# an existence question from topological groups

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

$G$ is a topological group, $A$ and $B$ are the subsets of $G$, we denote $AB$=$\{ab:a \in A, b\in B \}$.

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group, $m$ is a left Haar measure on $G$, $A$ and $B$ are two Borel subsets(generated by open subsets) in $G$, $0<m(A)<+ \infty$, $0<m(B)<+ \infty$, then there exist a $ x\in G$,such that $m(A \bigcap xB)>0$.

How to prove it?Is there any reference book about this proposition?

And if $0<m(A)  \leq + \infty$, $0<m(B) \leq+ \infty$, then there exist a $ x\in G$,such that $m(A \bigcap xB)>0$?

And if $0<m(A)< + \infty$, $0<m(B) <+ \infty$, then there exist a $ x\in G$,such that $m(A \bigcap Bx)>0$?

And if $0<m(A)< + \infty$, $0<m(B) <+ \infty$, then there exist a $ x\in G$,such that $m(A \bigcap xB^{-1})>0$?

Are these all right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a counterexample when you allow the sets to have infinite measure.  Let $H$ be an uncountable discrete group and $G=\mathbb{R}\times H$.  If $B$ is any set such that $B\cap \mathbb{R}\times \{h\}$ is closed for all $h\in H$ and nonempty for uncountably many $h\in H$, then $B$ is closed and $m(B)=\infty$ by outer regularity (any open neighborhood of $B$ must have non-null intersection with uncountably many $\mathbb{R}\times\{h\}$ and hence have infinite measure).  Now let $A=[0,1]\times \{1\}$ and let $B$ be the graph of some bijection between an uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and an uncountable subset of $H$.  Then $m(A)=1$ and $m(B)=\infty$, but any translate of $B$ will intersect $A$ in at most one point.

It is no coincidence that this example involves uncountable pathology: this can't happen if $G$ is $\sigma$-compact.  Indeed if $G$ is $\sigma$-compact, then its Haar measure is $\sigma$-finite, so if $B$ has positive measure, countably many translates of $B$ must cover almost all of $G$.  By countable additivity, every set of positive measure must have positive-measure intersection with one of these translates.

This also can't happen if $A$ and $B$ have finite measure.  Indeed, I claim that any Borel set $C$ of finite measure is contained in a $\sigma$-compact open subgroup $G_0$, so you can apply the argument of the previous paragraph to such a $G_0$ containing $C=A\cup B$.  To show this, let $K$ be any compact neighborhood of $1$; the subgroup $H$ generated by $K$ is then a $\sigma$-compact open subgroup of $G$.  By outer regularity, any Borel set $C$ of finite measure can only intersect countably many cosets of $H$ (since any neighborhood of $C$ must have non-null intersection with every coset of $H$ that $C$ intersects).  We can then take $G_0$ to be the subgroup generated by these countably many cosets.

This argument also gives a positive answer to your last two questions, since we can work in $G_0$ and the sets $Bx$ and $xB^{-1}$ still all have positive measure and so countably many of them cover almost all of $G_0$.

Comment: If we define $m'(B)$ as the supremum of $m(B\cap K)$ when $K$ ranges over $\sigma$-compact subsets, it seems that $m'$ behaves better with respect to the question?

Comment: $B$ can be chosen arbitrarily?

Comment: @YCor: Yes, that would seem to be better, though I'm not sure if it would make some other things go wrong.  Alternatively, my vague understanding is that you can avoid these sorts of problems by only defining the measure of Baire sets instead of Borel sets, so that sets like $B$ in my example aren't measurable.

Answer (score 4):

Let $1_A$ be the indicator function of $A$ and $1_{B^{-1}}$ the one of $B^{-1}$.
Then
$$
1_A*1_{B^{-1}}(x)=m(A\cap xB).
$$
But for the L^1-norm we have $\parallel 1_A*1_{B^{-1}}\parallel=\parallel 1_A\parallel \ \parallel 1_{B^{-1}}\parallel=m(A)m(B^{-1})$.
Now if $B$ has positive measure, ten so has $B^{-1}$ and therefore there exists $x$ with $m(A\cap xB)\ne 0$.

Comment: I knew this method. This is a slick proof. As a matter of fact, I was wondering if there is a nice solution without (any) integrals. But until now, I havn't find it...Oh my god...

Comment: Why do you ask if you know the result?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a nice solution without (any) integrals, I'd like an original answer about this. And in these questions, the last two questions may not be right.

Comment: This should have been explicit in your question.

Comment: Note that this argument implicitly uses some form of Fubini's theorem and so can run into trouble when Haar measure is not $\sigma$-finite; see my answer for details.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: The argument only uses Fubini on $A\times B$, which have finite measure, so there is no problem.

Comment: @Corbennick: Actually, I think it uses Fubini on something like $A\times AB$, but you're correct that (in the case that $A$ and $B$ have finite measure) there is no problem.